# estimating size of Java objects inside memcached

Tags: java, memory, memcached, spymemcached

I have a Java app that uses the spymemcached library (http://code.google.com/p/spymemcached) to read and write objects to memcached.

The app always caches the same type of object to memcached.  The cached object is always an ArrayList of 5 or 6 java.util.Strings.  Using the SizeOf library (http://www.codeinstructions.com/2008/12/sizeof-for-java.html), I've determined that the average deep size of the ArrayList is about 800 bytes.

Overall, I have allocated 12 GB of RAM to memcached.  My question is: How many of these objects can memcached hold?

It's not clear to me if it's correct to use the "800 byte" metric from SizeOf, or if that's misleading.  For example, SizeOf counts each char to be 2 bytes.  I know that every char in my String is a regular ASCII character. I believe spymemcached uses Java serialization, and I'm not sure if that causes each char to take up 1 byte or 2 bytes.

Also, I don't know how much per-object overhead memcached uses.  So the calculation should account for the RAM that memcached uses for its own internal data structures.

I don't need a number that's 100% exact.  A rough back-of-the-envelope calculation would be great.

Comment: You serialize Java objects to memcached?

Comment: Yes, it appears that spymemcached is using Java serialization.

Answer (score 4):

The simple approach would be experimentation:

1. restart memcache
2. Check bytes allocated: `echo "stats" | nc localhost 11211 | fgrep "bytes "`
3. insert 1 object, check bytes allocated
4. insert 10 objects, check bytes allocated
5. etc.

This should give you a good idea of bytes-per-key.

However, even if you figure out your serialized size, that alone probably won't tell you how many objects of that size memcache will hold.  Memcache's slab system and LRU implementation make any sort of estimate of that nature difficult.

Memcache doesn't really seem to be designed around guaranteeing data availability -- when you GET a key, it might be there, or it might not: maybe it was prematurely purged; maybe one or two of the servers in your pool went down.

Comment: This definitely solves the uncertainty around the number of bytes that's being sent over the wire after deserialization.  I don't need a guarantee that any particular object is in memcached.  I just need an estimate of how many objects will be in memcached once it's full.  The main piece of information that's still missing is how much overhead RAM memcached uses per object.